# Android : How to display a toast message when network is unavaliable

Tags: android, networking, toast

I have a data submit form in my activity, it is all done. What i need is a toast message  when submit button is clicked.  For no network, there should appear a toast & for network avaliable, my activity continues the job.

Comment: Nice. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean that SO is not a site to request code. You have to try something by your own and if you have issues/problems, then come and ask a question, and of course, include the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294607/check-network-available-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I gotcha! sorry for not posting code, i want that to be confidential. Please don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about check network availability in click event listener.

[How to check the network availability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404917/how-to-check-the-network-availability)

Comment: Sorry! that won't do the job. what i need id a toast that stops the onClick method if network is not avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom class to tackle this problem:

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Checking for all possible Internet providers
     * **/
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

you can implement this in your button on click listener:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            ConnectionDetector cd=new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()){
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Not connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                //your submit code
                            }

        }
    });
```

also add this permission to your manifest file:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

thanks for the tip @Warlock

Comment: Don't forget to add permission in your manifest - android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: Thnx, i'll try & reply :)